# How can I align my logo and menu icon on a mobile device

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using WordPress , I have a responsive theme that I am using as well. When I view my website on a mobile device, the menu turns into an icon with 3 horizontal lines; its a slide out menu.

On the mobile device the menu is above the 3 lines towards the left instead of them aligning with with each other.

This is the code for the menu icon:

```
.section-navi .pl-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 13px;
    /* opacity: .7; */
}
```

and this is the code for the logo:

```
.section-navi .navi-container {
    height: 36px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

please visit: surveillanceshack.com and view on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following code:

You might pick a suiting `@media` query [here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone), if you're targeting iPhones.

Almost every phone starts at `min-device-width: 320px`,  it's up to you to decide what you want as your top limit.

```css
// iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape   
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
  .section-navi .navi-container {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```